# Problem from Chatfield and Xing on State-Space Model

Tags: time-series, state-space-models

Chapter 10, Problem 2 from *The Analysis of Time Series* by Chatfield and Xing:

The problem says, "Consider the following special case of the linear growth model:"

$$ X_t = \mu_t + n_t $$
$$ \mu_t = \mu_{t-1} + \beta_{t-1} $$
$$ \beta_t = \beta_{t-1} + w_t $$

where $n_t$ and $w_t$ are independent normal with zero means and respective variances $\sigma_n^2$ and $\sigma_w^2$.

The problem has the solver show that the initial least squares estimator of the state vector at time 2, i.e., $[\mu_2, \beta_2]^{T}$, is $[X_2, X_2-X_1]$, and I'm good with that.

We are also to show that the covariance matrix for this vector is

$$P_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_n^2 & \sigma_n^2 \\ \sigma_n^2 & 2\sigma_n^2 + \sigma_w^2 \end{bmatrix} $$

This latter is tripping me up. The answer in the book seems to suggest that the expected value of $X_2 - X_1$ is $\beta_2$, for it computes $\mathrm{Var}[X_2-X_1]$ as

$$E[(X_2 - X_1 - \beta_2)^2] = E[(n_2-n_1+\beta_2-w_2-\beta_2)^2] = 2 \sigma_n^2 + \sigma_w^2 $$

But using the given system, one could either write $X_2 - X_1 = \beta_2 - w_2 + n_2 - n_1$ or as $X_2 - X_1 = \beta_1 + n_2 - n_1$. If I pretend that $\beta_2$ and $\beta_1$ are values that have been fixed by time 2, then the first leads to the expected value of $X_2 - X_1$ being $\beta_2$, but the second leads to it being $\beta_1$. Using $\beta_1$, the same computation as above would lead to

$$E[(X_2 - X_1 - \beta_2)^2] = 2\sigma_n^2 $$

It seems wrong to me to pretend the values $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are fixed and non-stochastic, and getting two different values seems to confirm my impression.

I guess I am confused about how any of these recursively-defined systems are started off, and the book doesn't seem to say. It only talks about *estimating* the initial values from the first few values of $X_t$. I would think that the initial value of $\beta_1$ would be $w_1$, and then I am happy with the value

$$\mathrm{Var}[X_2-X_1] = \mathrm{Var}[\beta_1 + n_2 - n_1] = 2 \sigma_n^2 + \sigma_w^2 $$

given as the answer. But then I would think that

$$ \mathrm{Var}[X_2] = \mathrm{Var}[\mu_1 + w_1 + n_1] $$

I don't know what to consider $\mu_1$ to be for this model, but I have trouble reconciling this thinking the the answer the book gives, that

$$ \mathrm{Var}[X_2] = \sigma_n^2 $$

Any guidance here is appreciated.

Comment: What is the distribution of $\mu_1$ and $\beta_1$?

Comment: It is not stated, and it is not clear to me that they are being treated as stochastic. That is part of my question here: is there a usually assumption in this sort of model, like beta_1 itself is just assumed to be w_1? In the computation given in the answer in the book, it seems that beta_2 is treated as an expected value, so is maybe being considered the (unobserved) state value at time 2 once data has been collected at time 2. But I'm not sure.